# New MYSQL-Server doesn't know JSON-datatype

Tags: php, mysql, json, phpmyadmin

I've set up a MYSQL-Server on a Raspberry Pi. Everything is working, but on importing the databases from my local server on Mac using PHPmyAdmin, the new MYSQL-Server doesn't accept the importing-files. It says I'm having an issue in my SQL-syntax. So I've tried to find the issue: It is an unknown datatype. In the local database here I used some times the datatype `json`, but the new MYSQL-Server doesn't know this datatype.

How to fix it?

Comment: and what are version of mysql on both platforms?

Comment: I assume RP works off default repo's just like all other *nix systems. So you have to assume that the default repo does not contain a particularly current version of MYSQL. Maybe you need to find a repo that does contain a newer MYSQL

Comment: you can change the data type from the database to VARCHAR (utf8_unicode_ci). I have MariaDB version 10.0.22 that does not have the json type either.

Comment: @JanWalczak Old one: `Server version: 5.7.13 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)`| New one: `Server version: 5.5.44-0+deb8u1 - (Raspbian)`

Comment: So that's why You can't use it. 5.7.8 was the first one to have it.

Comment: @JanWalczak Is there a way to update it on Raspbian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [JSON data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) was introduced in MySQL v5.7.8. If the new MySQL server does not support this data type, then it has a previous version. The solution is to upgrade the installed MySQL to a version that supports the JSON data type. Ideally, you should upgrade to the same version of MySQL that runs on your old server to avoid any further incompatibility issues.

Comment: I got this version using `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`, so I don't know how to get a newer version.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is a question of the superuser site, not for SO.